# All my Google Web Apps failed yesterday on 26 February 2024. does anyone know why?

Tags: google-apps-script

All my Google Web Apps (there are 90 of them) failed yesterday on 26 February 2024. They are all working today without me doing anything to them as I only found out about the failure this morning. Does anyone know why? The client side error reads: **We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code INTERNAL** So the HTML file failed to load for them in all cases.

The execution history just says failed on the doGet function:

```
function doGet(e) {
    const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form');
    htmlOutput.email = userEmail;
    return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

Does anyone know what could have caused this?

Comment: I think that this issue is due to Google side. You can see it at [here](https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status?product=WORKSPACE&product_group=GOOGLE_WORKSPACE) and [here](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/incidents/DR1JYH2tW69g9BobX8e6?hl=en).